# Point (x,y) coordinates sort lower to higher in Python

Tags: python, list, algorithm, numpy, random

Random points in "points" list. Like this : [x,y] = ([3,4],[2,5],[0,7],[8,1]) .

But i need to do these process ;

- First one , i have to sort points in list like lower Y and lower X as a point double.(For example [1,2],[1,3]) .
- Second one, how can i do action in list like this ; (Y0-Y1 / X0-X1) .

Here is my codes ;

```
import numpy as np
points = np.random.randint(0, 9, size=(18,2))
print(points)
```

Comment: I did not understand your sorting approach.

Comment: @Mbo for example , you have a list like this [ [1,2] , [5,4] , [5,5] ,[1,3] ] 
--> sort list which had lower x and y . like this : [ [1,2] , [ 1,3] ,[ 5,4],[5,5] ] 
--> in this list index 0  = [1,2] ,  index 1 = [1,3]
--> i 'm trying to calculate Y0-Y1 / X0-X1 . On this example   (  2-3 / 1-1  ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want to sort list using X-field as primary key and Y-field as secondary key. I provide lambda function for this sorting, but really it is default behaviour of sort function.

Don't know how you are going to treat division by zero, so return `None` for vertical segments:

```
s =  [ [1,2] , [ 1,3] ,[ 5,4],[5,5] ]
s = sorted(s, key = lambda a: (a[0], a[1]))
#s = sorted(s) should give the same result
print(s)
slopes = [(a[1] - b[1]) / (a[0] - b[0]) if (a[0] - b[0])!=0 else None 
              for a, b in zip(s[:-1], s[1:])]
print(slopes)

[[1, 2], [1, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5]]
[None, 0.25, None]
```